# I got Abortado when executing rpmbuild on debian

Tags: debian, rpmbuild

I am trying to build using rpmbuild but the only thing I get is a "Abortado" message.

If I ask for the version I get it:

```
rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.8.1
```

But if I try to build a spec I can't:

```
rpmbuild -bb service.spec
Abortado
```

I have just installed the rpm on my debian via apt-get install rpm.

If L use it as root it works, but with another user it don't.

What do you thing is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have it working on debian and i have the following installed

```
rpmbuild --version
RPM version 4.12.0.1
more /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux stretch/sid \n \l
```

Can you try it with the following and past the output? It will give a better output.

```
rpmbuild -v -bb service.spec
```

I might be some thing in your spec file that is making it fail.